# How to broadcast to all linked processes?

Tags: process, erlang, publish-subscribe, broadcast

Let's say I have a process X and he's linked to 3 other processes [U, Y, Z]. How can I broadcast a message from X to those processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [`process_info/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_info-2) documentation:

```
broadcast_to_linked(Message) ->
  {links, Links} = process_info(self(), links),
  Fun = fun(P) -> P ! Message end,
  lists:foreach(Fun, Links).
```

Comment: Requirements have changed, I'm sending messages to processes on different nodes now. I've tried tweaking your solution but I'm getting this error: =ERROR REPORT==== 12-Apr-2014::12:26:00 ===
Error in process <0.89.0> on node 'sub@Molly' with exit value: {badarg,[{subscri
ber,'-broadcast/2-fun-0-',3,[{file,"subscriber.erl"},{line,27}]},{lists,foreach,
2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1323}]},{subscriber,loop,0,[{file,"subscriber.erl"},
{line,38}]}]}

I tweaked ur code like this:

`broadcast(Msg, Reason) ->
`Fun = fun(P) -> P ! {self(), Msg, Reason} end,
`lists:foreach(Fun, nodes()).

Answer (score 4):

You can find links with erlang:process_info/2 like

```
[Pid ! Msg || Pid <- element(2, process_info(self(), links))]
```

Comment: The argument I have against using the comprehension is that you end up with a result you don't need. :-)

Comment: Yeah, also Dialyzer might complain. Use [lists:foreach/2](http://erldocs.com/17.0-rc1/stdlib/lists.html?i=0&search=lists:foreach#foreach/2) instead.

Comment: At the end I don't need to broadcast to linked processes. I need to broadcast to known nodes. I'm trying to do it this way but it's not working, can you help?

     receive Msg ->
          case Msg of ->
                _Other ->
                    [Pid ! {self(), Msg} || Pid <- lists:foreach(nodes())]

EDIT: How do I format code in comments?

Comment: What do you mean "broadcast to nodes"? Erlang messages are always delivered to processes. (Use backquotes for code in comments.)

Comment: I have two nodes and I start one process on each node. I want to send messages between those processes. The first problem is how one node discovers the other? The second problem is how to send a message between processes that are on different nodes?